# Springboot app | Requests not reaching to application but reaching to tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have spring boot application deployed in private cloud.
This application is being hit by one upstream application.
The issue is that if upstream system is hitting one of the API of my application, almost 99% of the requests are not reaching to spring controller, I am not seeing any application logs for them, but I am seeing tomcat access logs and its returning with httpStatus 200.
The upstream systems logs printing a error "Not found"

However if I hit the API via Postman or Jmeter, all the curls are getting successful.

I haven't configured or added any of the tomcat specific properties. All default values are being used.

Please help with this and please let me know if any more information is required.
I am not attaching any of the code here as this will violate company guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I think your problem is related to CORS, have a look at this - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors

I think you need to add this to your code:

```
@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
            registry.addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST")
                    .allowedOrigins("http://upstream-application-url");
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response. But I don't think it is related to CORS, as via postman it is working and I am not specifying same host there as that of the service. Its working in lower environments, but not in production.